# Javascript not working on Chrome but files are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am developing a website an everything works properly with Safari but in Chrome not.

With the Chrome development tools I can see that all files were loaded:

```
<script src="http://web.local/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://web.local/flat-ui/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://web.local/js/script.js"></script>
```

I can see the source code of these files and the Network tab also indicates that the files where loaded. However, the following error appears:

```
net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

And more concretely:

```
Name: web.local
Method: GET
Status: (failed)
Text: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
Type: text/html
Initiator: web.local/:1 Parser
```

**EDIT:**

It's a server issue for sure. If I download the site and open the html file, everything works.

Any idea of what could happen?

Comment: What is in `script.js`?

Comment: This could be a server issue. What kind of server are you using to serve the JavaScript files?

Comment: `$(function() { alert('hi'); });`@putvande

Comment: I am using Laravel Craft version 1.0.0 with the server MAMP 2.1.3 @RickvanMook

Comment: Actually, Looks like the load our your actual html site goes wrong, in that either it was interrupted sometime after the scripts tags were transmitted or the server produces a wrong chunked encoding int the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I had to upgrade MAMP to version 3.0.5 and now everything works fine.

I've read that this could be caused by php version, the current one es 5.5.10.